# Is a disjoint union locally a cartesian product?

Tags: category-theory, vector-bundles

A vector bundle $(E,p, B)$ can be viewed as a disjoint union of all its fibers, $E = \coprod_{x\in B}E_x$. Through vector bundle charts, we can describe $E$, at least in a neighbourhood of the base space, $U\subset B$,
as $$p^{-1}(U)\simeq_{\Phi} U \times \mathbb{R}^n ,$$ where the identification is made via a bundle chart $\Phi$.

My question is the following, from a categorical point of view, can we always express a disjoint union, locally, as a cross product? Or is this property, what characterizes vector bundles?

Comment: Are you asking whether this holds: $(\text{copy of $A$})\overset.\cup(\text{copy of $A$})\cong A\times\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Your question made me think that **yes** this is precisely what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an index set $I$. If you have a disjoint union of $I$-many copies of $X$, then this is [*by definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union#Set_theory_definition) the set

$$X\times I.$$

So the only question remaining is whether this also yields the same topology in general (and not just for vector bundles). And the answer is *Yes*, if we equip $I$ with the discrete topoloy:

*Proof*.

We have two topologies on $X\times I$ which we have to show are equal:

- *Sum topology*: $U\subseteq X\times I$ is open if and only if $U_i:=\{x\in X\mid (x,i)\in U\}\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ for all $i\in I$.
- *Product topology*: $U\subset X\times I$ is open if and only if it is the arbitrary union of sets $U_X\times U_I$, where $U_X\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ and $U_I\subseteq I$ is open in $I$.

$\Rightarrow:\;$

Assume $U_i:=\{x\in X\mid (x,i)\in U\}$ is open for all $i\in I$. Then $U$ is the union of the sets $U_i\times\{i\}$ and $U_i$ is open in $X$ and $\{i\}$ is open in $I$.

$\Leftarrow:\;$

Assume $U$ is the union of sets $U_{X,k}\times U_{I,k}$ for some index set $K$. Define $\mathfrak U_i:=\{U_{X,k}\mid k\in K,i\in U_{I,k}\}$. Then

$$U_i 
=\left\{x\in X\mid (x,i)\in U\right\}
=\bigcup_{U\in \mathfrak U_i}U.
$$

Since all the $U\in\mathfrak U_i$ are open, and $U_i$ is their union, $U_i$ is open too.

$\square$

---

If however $I$ is not equipped with the discrete topology, then this is not true anymore. A topology is discrete if and only if all points $\{i\}$ are open sets. So if it is not discrete, there is some $i\in I$, so that $\{i\}$ is not open anymore. This means

$$X\times\{i\}$$

is not open in $X\times I$ w.r.t to the product topology. But $X\times\{i\}$ is open w.r.t. the sum topology. So the product $X\times I$ (the simplest bundle) cannot be seen as a disjoint union of $I$-many copies of $X$, at least not using the obvious identity map $\mathrm{id}$ as homeomorphism.

Comment: *If* $I$ is actually a manifold, without the discrete topology?

Comment: @EEEB Okay, I see. But then I doubt that a vector bundle can (in general) be expressed as the disjoint union of its fibers, since this would imply $I$ to be discrete. Where do you have this statement from?

Comment: Nowhere, it's my own question I try to answer. In general there should be topological obstructions to expressing disjoint union as a product.

Comment: Also another motivation I had, was the following: A function $\Phi: A\times B \to C$ is hard to analyse, because the product is in the domain. There, would seem to be some way to analyse it, if we could somehow replace the product domain, at least locally?, by a coproduct, for then coproducts are defined to naturally have functions out of them.

Comment: @EEEB I added a part to my answer which explains the other direction. If this not helps, then I am out of luck :D I am not a topologist.