# What is wrong with this proof $M\times \mathbb{R}^n$ diffeomorphic to $TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

$TM$ is the tangent bundle. Since it is defined as the disjoint union, it is the same set as $M\times \mathbb{R}^n$. Just construct the function
$$\begin{align*}
f: M\times \mathbb R^n\, &\longrightarrow\, TM\\
(x,u)\,&\longrightarrow (x,u).
\end{align*}$$
Since the coordinate chart on $TM$ is defined as $(U,\varphi)$ where $U=\pi^{-1}(V)$ for $V$ open in $M$ and
$$
\varphi\left(v^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)= (x,u),
$$
it looks like the function constructed above is identity with respect to this coordinate chart. I feel like the tangent bundle is trying to capture the relation between the point and the corresponding tangent space, but since the tangent bundle is defined as a disjoint union, it seems like it is the same as cartesian product.

Comment: The important part is the topology on this disjoint union, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2609137/452113

Comment: Not enough explicitation of your notation, please improve the OP.

Comment: Bit of a side note : you should never think of $TM$ as a disjoint union of tangent spaces (because it ignores the topology). This presentation is both error-inducing and completely unnecessary, so I am baffled by the frequency at which I see it in introductory books and course notes.

Comment: @D.Thomine Thanks for comment. I am using the Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold.  It defines the underline set as disjoint product, and use the coordinate chart in the question to generate a topology on the manifold. But how does this disproves the function above is not a diffeomorphism? It seems like this is trying to make the function in the question as a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Your $f$ is not well defined. It depends on local coordinates.

Comment: @ArcticChar Why is that? If I think of $TM$ as $T\mathbb{R}^n$ and fix some random basis for each $T_p\mathbb{R}^n$, there is no ambiguity for the definition itself.

Comment: ar, okay. But then there's no reason to think that $f$ would be even continuous. And $f$ should be really $f(x, u_1, \cdots, u_n) = (x, u_1 e_1(x) + \cdots u_n e_n(x))$, where $\{e_1(x), \cdots, e_n(x)\}$ are the basis at $x$.

Comment: As @ArcticChar points out, this map isn't well defined. If you have two overlapping coordinate patches $U$ and $V$ you have two choices for where to send $(x,\vec{v})$ (with $x\in U\cap V$).

Comment: @ArcticChar but for the defn of diffeomorphism, we only require that for each $p$, there exists chart $(U,\varphi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$, and $f$ is diffeomorphic with respect to these two charts (so we don't require $f$ to be continuous in the first place). And for these charts, I think we can always pick $U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ at both sides?

Comment: Your own definition mentions coordinate charts and the tangent vectors $\frac\partial{\partial x^i}$ are relative to the coordinates in a chart. If you fix every basis before hand you get a bijection that has no reason whatsoever to be continuous.

Comment: @Zorualyh Yes you can choose $U\times \mathbb R^n$ on both side, but under these chart your map is not continuous, let alone differentiable (But to continue, can you confirm that the map I wrote is the one you have in mind?)

Comment: @ArcticChar Oh, I see! $f$ is indeed not well-defined. If $M$ cannot be covered by a single chart, then I cannot fix the basis of $TM$ beforehand!

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Ah I see, thanks for pointing it out.